# Solve $5x+11y=4\pmod{13}$

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, integers

Now, I know if $ax+by=c$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then first try $au+bv=1$ and hence from $ax+by=acu+bcv$ we get $\frac{x-cu}{-b}=\frac{y-cv}{a}$ and as both are integers, the solutions are, $$x=-bn+cu,\, y=an+cv.$$
Now, in this equation, I need to use $\bmod 13$, which I don't know how to?
Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean _congruent to_ or _equal to_ in your title?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You have the equation of a line in the (finite) plane $\mathbf F_{13}^2$, so I think all you have to obtain is the list of the thirteen points on this line.

To this end, you have to express $y$ in function of $x$ or the converse:
$$y=11^{-1}(4-5x)\quad\text{ or }\quad x=5^{-1}(4-11y),$$
and therefore to determine the inverse of $11$ or of $5\bmod 13$ using Bézout's relation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's done, but what if i see mod 133 in place of mod 13, then surely i can't check all element separately. Is there any method to do that?

Comment: 133 is 7*19 so there exists inverse for 5 and 11 mod 133. So it is the same method

Comment: For $133$, you'd have to solve  $\bmod 7$  and $\bmod 19$, then use the *Chinese remainder theorem* to obtain the solutions $\bmod 133$. For a bigger prime, I guess the only thing to do is using a maths program to get the list. But is it that interesting?

Answer (score 0):

Your equations for x any y must give following solutions:

$$5x+11y≡4 \ mod (13)=13 n+4$$

$n=1, 2, 3, 4, ....$

$13n+4=17, 30, 43, 56, 49, 62, 75, 88, 101, 114, 147, 160, 173, . . .$

which gives(from 43):

$(x, y)=(2, 3), (9, 1),(1, 4), (8, 2), (4, 5), (11, 3), (7, 6), (3, 9), (14, 7), (10, 10), (17, 8)$

Therefore solutions are:

$x ≡2 \ mod (13)$, $y ≡3 \ mod (13)$

Such that:

$5x+11y≡43 \ mod (13) ≡ 4 \ mod (13)$

$x ≡ 9 \mod (13)$, $y ≡ 1 \mod (13)$

$x ≡14 \mod(13)≡ 1 \mod(13)$, $y≡7 \mod(13)$

$x≡17 \mod(13)≡4 \mod (13)$, $y ≡ 8 \mod (13)$

And so on.